# Compiz/Unity doesn't start at login

Tags: unity, 12.10, compiz, login

Out of a sudden after I logging in to the 'Ubuntu' session Unity or maybe Compiz doesn't start anymore (actually I'm not sure wether it is Compiz or Unity). I can start Unity manually with `setsid unity &` and put the command as a startup script but that's not how it should be.

I also tried a lot of "solutions" but none of them helped:

- checked for activated 'Unity' module in ccsm
- reinstalled lightdm
- reset Compiz and Unity
- reinstalled all Compiz/Unity packages
- many more...

The question now is, how do I get Compiz/Unity to be started propperly at login again?

I'm on 12.10 with Intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add one startup application:

1. Open a terminal and type the following command:

   ```
   unity && compiz --replace
   ```
2. If step 1 works for your situation, open `unity-dash-home` and type `startup`. You should see **Startup Applications**.

   In the program, add a startup application with the command:

   ```
   compiz --replace
   ```
3. Log out and login, things should be solved.

Comment: Meanwhile I got a new Laptop which 'solved' this problem by a clean install.
Sadly this is only a workaround which for me worked only when I put a big pause in the startup script. So what I was really interested in was to know the reason why Unity/Compiz didn't start as intended and how to get evrything working fine without a workaround.